# How To Replace All Letters To Underscore

Tags: java

I am making a hangman game. I want to change all letters(lower and uppercase) to underscore. Here is my code:

```
    _answer = "HANGMAN";
    Log.i("Word", "Answer orig: " + _answer);
    _answer = _answer.replaceAll("/[a-zA-Z]+/g", "_");
    Log.i("Word", "Answer underscore: " + _answer);
```

The output is:

```
Answer orig: HANGMAN
Answer underscore: HANGMAN
```

My code did not replace the letters to underscore.

Comment: Start by remove the leading and trailing `/` and the `g` from the regex. They don't belong there. They are used by other languages as an alternative to quoting and to specify options.

Comment: Yeah, those are Perl/vim.  Java doesn't use that syntax.

Comment: If you are trying to develop the hangman game, a much better way of doing things is using a simple `char` array to hold the `_answer` as you call it.
Array lookup will be much faster and less prone to errors than a regex.

Furthermore, at every stage you will find that as characters are guessed, managing the regex will become cumbersome.

Comment: @markspace Andreas Thanks guys. I'm not really familiar with regex, just copied it online. This helped me :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to change "each" letter to an underscore.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String _answer = "HANGMAN";
    _answer = _answer.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "_"); // replace each letter with an "_"
    System.out.println(_answer);

}
```

O/P :

```
_______
```

Note : You can also use `(?i)` to make it case -insensitive

```
_answer = _answer.replaceAll("(?i)[a-z]", "_");
```

Answer (score 1):

In some programming languages, you can specify a regex like this:

```perl
/[a-zA-Z]+/g
```

This is language-specific syntax for defining a regex, and the `g` means "global", i.e. repeat as many times as necessary.

In **Java**, a regex is given as a String literal. There is no special regex syntax.

The `g` option is not used, but you get the same behavior by choosing the right method: [`replaceFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) means once-only, and [`replaceAll()][1]` is the same as specifying the `g` (global) option.

So, `replaceAll("/[a-zA-Z]+/g", "_")` should be `replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]+", "_")`.

If you didn't have the `g`, you'd have used `replaceFirst("[a-zA-Z]+", "_")`.

---

However, you said *"change all letters(lower and uppercase) to underscore"*. Did you mean "all letters to a *single* underscore" (which is what you're trying to do), or did you mean "*each* letter to an underscore"?

If the latter, use one of these:

```
replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "_")
replaceAll("(?i)[a-z]", "_")       // Flag: CASE_INSENSITIVE
replaceAll("\\p{Alpha}", "_")      // POSIX: An alphabetic character [\p{Lower}\p{Upper}]

// For non-english letter support:
replaceAll("(?U)\\p{Alpha}", "_")  // Flag: UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS
replaceAll("\\p{L}", "_")          // Unicode letter category
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String word = "HUNUMAN"; 
    StringBuilder gletters = new StringBuilder("_"); 
    String mainword = word.replaceAll("[^" + gletters + "]", "_");
    System.out.println(mainword);
}
```

Comment: Why bother with string builder at all?

Comment: That would replace all characters (not only letters) by _